# How to check numerical value from Django queryset?

Tags: python, python-3.x

tokens = User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=day)).values().

How do I check passed user_id  of the queryset so I can use it?

Answer (score 0):

tokens = User.objects.filter(date_joined__gte=datetime.now()-timedelta(days=day)).values().

This tokens variable will contain a user object and you can get the id of this queryset by tokens.id